# How can I cancel an inputting when a previously defined time is over

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new in C++. I want to create such a program in this language through the codeblocks where, we will be told to enter a specific value within a specific time. If we enter a value within the specific time it will work accordingly, but if we delay the program will be over. 
Help me, by adding a code if you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It practically is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific, since the C++11 (or C++14 or C++17) standard don't offer any such facilities (the only standardized way of getting [input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) being C++ streams such as [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) or C stdio files à la `FILE*`). You probably need some external libraries.

On Linux or POSIX systems, consider (for a [terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)) some library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Perhaps a multiplexing system call, à la [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), should be useful (for the timeout).

Perhaps you want a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) interface. Then look into [Qt](http://qt.io/) (or some other [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)).